# Whatsapp URL error ' Phone number shared via url is invalid" even if mobile number is active on whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp

I am using Selenium.webdriver to send message on whatsapp using URL

```
"url = 'https://web.whatsapp//send?phone='+lead+'&text=' + message"
```

but its showing error after yesterday(16/11/2022)

> Phone number shared via url is invalid

how can it be resolved?

Number is a valid whatsapp user. but still url showing error

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? Facing the same issue since the last week.

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp has stopped the ability to send messages with short urls like wa.me for people who are not registered in your contacts. It is not clear at the moment whether he did this permanently or if this situation will improve after a while.

As a workaround, you need to save numbers in bulk in your contacts. I showed it in detail in the video here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUWeO2GMazY

**To summarize**

1. we list destination numbers without country code.
2. export phone numbers to google spreadsheet. Make column header phone and download as .csv
3. Import the .csv file in the google contacts app.
4. export again as vcard by selecting export option
5. open the contacts list on your phone and select the import option. Import the vcard file
6. After doing these steps, you can send a message to their phone
   number.

Remember this is a temporary solution. I hope whatsapp will be restored soon because many people use short urls to send messages